# When to use double braces in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, xss, laravel-blade, curly-braces

I want to know when to use {{}} and when {!!!!} in Laravel? I know that it is an approach to prevent XSS but I have seen that all developers use {{}} for even the image address, stylesheet address, script address and so on while as I know XSS is something that can be done with malicious user INPUT not the one that is static and is set by developer. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data):

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use this thumb rule: Unless you need to output rendered HTML, use {{ }}. Else, use {!! !!}

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right. if you want to escape the user input data then use {{}}, it is just like htmlentities function and if you don't want to escape the data then you can use {!!!!}.

Comment: So why other developers as I have seen use only {{}} in all parts without paying attention on what it is?